# How do I add a template function pointer as a value parameter to a map

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a working framework where I'm using a map to run a certain function given a certain enum. This just now has led to me having a lot of functions, all with the same signature, and a lot of them with identical code. As such, I'd like to provide a template function pointer as the value in the map. 
This is the working setup:

```
QMap <ENUM,OutputWidget *(MainWindow::*)()>func_map;
OutputWidget *handle_first();
OutputWidget *handle_second();

func_map{{FIRST,&MainWindow::handle_first},{SECOND,&MainWindow::handle_second}};
OutputWidget *output1 = (this->*func_map[FIRST])();
OutputWidget *output2 = (this->*func_map[SECOND])();
```

I'd like to be able to alter the func_map to handle this signature too, but I haven't been able to figure out how to:

```
    template <typename INPUTTYPE,typename OUTPUTTYPE> OUTPUTTYPE *handle_all();
```

I've tried adding this template to the map as so;

```
    func_map{{FIRST,&MainWindow::handle_first},SECOND,&MainWindow::handle_second},{THIRD,&MainWindow::handle_all<FirstInputWidget,ThirdOutputWidget>}}
```

But that has resulted in the following error:

```
../TemplateTest/mainwindow.cpp: In constructor ‘MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)’:../TemplateTest/mainwindow.cpp:9:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘QMap<ENUM, OutputWidget* (MainWindow::*)()>::QMap(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
          }
```

Being able to add this template would cut down on a LOT of my code. If anyone has any ideas on how to implement this I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, a *function-template* is ***not*** a *function*. You have to **instantiate** a *function-template* to "produce" a *function* (which you can then take its address). You can only map an instantiated specialization of `handle_all()` *function-template*.

Comment: did you forget the `(INPUTTYPE)` in `OUTPUTTYPE* handle_all(INPUTYPE)` ?

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do. You want a map with arbitrary function pointers as value type ?

Comment: as there is no such thing as a template function pointer, imho it would help if you show an example of what you want to do with such a map. In your working example, you know the parameter and the return type, so you can call the functions, but I wouldnt know what to do with a map that contains arbitrary functions...

Comment: Full errors are required.  Ideally a [MCVE] with extra code not needed to generate error eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

No real issue here, you just need to take the address of an instance of the function template:

```
func_map{
    {FIRST,  &MainWindow::handle_all<FirstType, OutputWidget>},
    {SECOND, &MainWindow::handle_all<SecondType, OutputWidget>}
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and got the following error: `/home/doug/workspace/Qt_Projects/TemplateTest/mainwindow.cpp:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘QMap<ENUM, OutputWidget* (MainWindow::*)()>::QMap(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
 {SECOND,&(MainWindow::handle_all<SecondInputWidget,SecondOutputWidget>)}}
                                                                         ^`

Comment: @ManSizeRooster drop the parentheses after the `&` -- pointer-to-members have a fixed syntax that does not support them.

Comment: Point taken, I shouldn't have had the parenthesis. They've been removed and the error still shows.

`error: no matching function for call to ‘QMap<ENUM, OutputWidget* (MainWindow::*)()>::QMap(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’`

Comment: @ManSizeRooster you should update your question with your new code, and the full error message.